# Implementing traits for fn type

Tags: function, rust, traits

I want to implement custom trait for several concrete functions, i.e.

```
trait ToTarget {
    fn custom_str(&self) -> String;
}

impl ToTarget for fn() -> String {
    fn custom_str(&self) -> String {
        self()
    }
}

impl ToTarget for fn(i32) -> String {
    fn custom_str(&self) -> String {
        self(4)
    }
}

fn a() -> String {
    "abc".to_string()
}

fn b(x: i32) -> String {
    x.to_string()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", b.custom_str());
}
```

However, this does not compile giving the next error:

```
<anon>:26:22: 26:34 error: no method named `custom_str` found for type `fn(i32) -> collections::string::String {b}` in the current scope
<anon>:26     println!("{}", b.custom_str());
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in expansion of format_args!
<std macros>:2:25: 2:56 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 2:62 note: in expansion of print!
<std macros>:3:1: 3:54 note: expansion site
<std macros>:1:1: 3:58 note: in expansion of println!
<anon>:26:5: 26:36 note: expansion site
<anon>:26:22: 26:34 help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope; the following trait defines an item `custom_str`, perhaps you need to implement it:
<anon>:26:22: 26:34 help: candidate #1: `ToTarget`
error: aborting due to previous error
playpen: application terminated with error code 101
```

However, If I specify the type of b, code compiles:

```
println!("{}", (b as fn(i32) -> String).custom_str());
```

So the question is: is there a way to make my first version of code with

```
println!("{}", b.custom_str());
```

compile? Specifying type of function every time I want to use my trait is really annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that every function has its very own type, but might have the same signature as another function. You implemented the trait `ToTarget` for all functions with the signature `fn(i32) -> String`.

As an example: your function `b` has type `fn(i32) -> collections::string::String {b}` (note the `{b}` in the type), but you cannot specify this type explicitly.

What you can do is implement `ToTarget` for all types that that implement `Fn(i32) -> String`:

```
trait ToTarget {
    fn custom_str(&self) -> String;
}

impl<T> ToTarget for T where T: Fn(i32) -> String {
    fn custom_str(&self) -> String {
        self(4)
    }
}

fn b(x: i32) -> String {
    x.to_string()
}
```

But then you cannot implement `ToTarget` for `Fn() -> String` or any other types for that matter, since there might be a type that implements `Fn(i32) -> String` AND `Fn() -> String`, which would yield two different implementations for the same type. As far as I can see, even [impl specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1210) won't help here, so you are out of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure what effect this would have, but maybe it's a no-brainer to make sure that all functions with the same signature can be coerced into that signature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My first attempt was to implement `ToTarget` for `Fn` trait, but as soon as I wrote second implementation I found out that I can't have second implementation of ToTarget for trait. I think I'll switch to macros in this particular case.